# How to group by one of the elements in a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have the following values:

```
values = [('Foo', 1), ('Bar', 3), ('FooBar', 1)]
```

I'd want to group these values in a dictionary, by one of the tuple elements, say for instance, the last element.

The expected output would be:

```
print expected_output
>>> { 1: ['Foo', 'FooBar'], 3: ['Bar'] }
```

I'm looking for a Python 2.x compatible solution.

Furthermore, the solution should not be coupled to the tuple's element type (in this case, `int`).

What'd be the most pythonic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for val, key in tuples:
  result[key].append(val)

result = dict(result)
```

Comment: `result = {}` and `result.setdefault(key, []).append(val)` also work.  Just in case you don't want to use `defaultdict`.  But of course, using it makes it cleaner code.